is it legal to have a c environment where char is 16 bits and short is also 16 bits
I am trying to create (new backend for tinyc) a c compiler for a very odd machine. Its only addressable unit is a 16 bit word, ie it cannot address at the 8 bit byte level. Its natural int size is 16 too.
As far as I can see the c standard says that char must be at least 8 bits, and that short must be at least 16. But there is nothing that says sizeof(char) cannot = sizeof(short).
It feels weird to be even thinking about a system like that, we all have such a strong mental model of what chars and shorts etc look like in ram.
My alternative is to be 'normal' in data types and emulate 8 bit behavior by fetching words and chopping them up. My issue there is that there are no shift or rotate instructions so it would be very expensive to do (emulating right shift even by one bit in order to do a word fetch for a byte needs at least 32 instructions, test and set each bit, or do a long rotate left). Feels like my 100mhz fpga would be running at 2mhz

On DSPs it's very common to have 16-bit char/short. Some even has 24-bit char and 24-bit short

If sizeof(char) == sizeof(int), then I don't see any reasonable way to implement the function fgetc, because the return value of the function would be unable to represent the entire range of unsigned char values, or at least not in a way that these values are distinguishable from the value EOF.

@AndreasWenzel: That has been discussed previously on Stack Overflow. As I recall, the inability to distinguish EOF is a nuisance but not insurmountable.

@AndreasWenzel: Here.

@AndreasWenzel so it requires that size of int > size of char . Which I am ok with. I assume that's why fgetc returns into, not short

@pm100 If you do not like sizeof(char) == sizeof(short), make char 16-bit, short 32-bit, etc.

Note: platforms that have char as 16 bits (e.g. TI DSPs) are not posix compliant. Posix mandates that CHAR_BIT is 8.

@CraigEstey that seems like a killer then . Rats

If portability to a platform where sizeof(int) == 1 is a concern, then fgetc calls could be replaced with fread.

@CraigEstey gonna have to go with plan b. Lose half my ram by addressing words as though they were bytes.

@pm100 Side note: I'm on a personal quest to stamp out oddball arches that torture C and programmers. TI DSPs (char==16 bits), Intel 8051 (uses different insts and different sizeof for pointers), PIC* (banked memory), Sperry/Univac/Burroughs (36 bit words), PDP/8 (self modifying code on call/return). The "stamp" list is "do not use in future designs" and "replace all existing boards". May I ask what CPU/arch you're referring to so I can add it to the list? ;-)

@CraigEstey the hack system from here https://www.nand2tetris.org/ i have it implemented in an fpga and wanted to get a c compiler for it. its like trying to run a marathon backwards with only one leg


is it legal to have a c environment where char is 16 bits and short is also 16 bits

Yes.

but you wont be posix compliant, so it means i cant use the vast existing c code base. I was hoping to compile an old unix

I like short answers and I cannot lie. Take your tick

The only requirement C places on the width of char and short is that char must be at least 8 bits and short must be at least 16 bits, and at least as big as char, because char must be the smallest addressable type. So yes, it is legal.
My citation is section 5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types:

Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.


number of bits for smallest object that is not a bit-field (byte)
CHAR_BIT 8



maximum value for an object of type unsigned short int
USHRT_MAX 65535 // 2^16 − 1



Also relevant: §6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters and integers where it defines the conversion ranks.  Notably: — No two signed integer types shall have the same rank, even if they have the same representation. — The rank of a signed integer type shall be greater than the rank of any signed integer type with less precision. — The rank of long long int shall be greater than the rank of long int, which shall be greater than the rank of int, which shall be greater than the rank of short int, which shall be greater than the rank of signed char.

@ikegami No, the C99 also has the requirement that CHAR_BIT >= 8

The real question is 'how much software out there assumes that char is 8bit and that short is 2 bytes'. The reason for creating a c compiler is to be able to use the vast library of existing software. I bet a ton would break .

@pm100 Software that does 'unsafe' operations such as type punning, or relying on overflow. This is why I always use the intX_t types to avoid ambiguity, and fail early if the implementation does not support what I want.

@JonathanLeffler isnt that sayng that sizeof (char ) == sizeof (short) is illegal then?

@pm100 No, rank is not the same as size. Rank is for example when you try to perform a binary operation, what is the type of the final expression.

@pm100 All basic integers types could have the same bit-width (without padding) and still meet the rank issue.

@CPlus plus any code that asks for uint8_t, i cant support that without doing the horrific emulation

@pm100 But at least it would fail off the bat, instead of seeming to work but causing unexpected results at some point.

@pm100 — no (that doesn't mean that sizeof(char) == sizeof(short) is illegal).  "No two signed integer types shall have the same rank, even if they have the same representation" recognizes that two types can have the same representation (size).  There is a lot of densely worded standardese verbiage that I didn't quote — a lot of it is inscrutable — but between the various sections, you end up with sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) && sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) && sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) && sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long).
